# formattable object in a R Sweave (RNW) document

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, formattable

I am using the `formattable` package for better-looking data frames in R. Let's say my data looks as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(Typ=c("Winners","","Losers",""),
               Time=c("1.","2.","1.","2."),
               Value=percent(c(0.22,0.18,0.78,0.82)),
               Change=percent(c(NA,-0.04,NA,0.04)))
formattable(df, list(
  Change=formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green")),
    x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)))
)
```

In this way everything works properly (in the RStudio preview and in HTML documents), but when I try to put this table in R Sweave documents it is not rendered.

I tried to use `format_table` which output is a `knit_kable` object or `knit_print` but neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

Loosely speaking, the question is: **How to use `formattable` (or in general: a function that generates markdown/HTML output) in a RNW document?**

## Background

At first, I thougt the approach I suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598367/2706569) could be applied. It allows to embed markdown markup in a RNW document. But as it turned out, `formattable` produces a mix of markdown and HTML output – in this case, that approach won't work.

About 3 weeks ago, [fdetsch posted a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35550394/2706569) that shows how to embed `leaflet` (or in general: `htmlWidget`s) in RNW documents. This answer builds on and extends fdetsch's solution.

## The solution (raw)

- Install the `webshot` library from GitHub and, if necessary, `devtools` and `htmlwidgets`.

  ```
  devtools::install_github("wch/webshot")
  ```
- Save the return value of `formattable` in an object (I used `mytable`).
- Convert `mytable` to an `htmlWidget`: `as.htmlwidget(mytable)`
- Save the widget to a temporary HTML file (should be in current working directory, see below):

  ```
  tmpHTML <-  basename(tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
  saveWidget(as.htmlwidget(mytable), file = tmpHTML)
  ```
- Take a "screenshot" of the HTML file. For some reason, `webshot` produces empty image files when passing in a path instead of a filename.

  ```
  myImage <- "image.pdf"
  webshot(tmpHTML, file = myImage, cliprect = "viewport")
  ```
- Add the figure to the document:

  ```
  knitr::include_graphics(myImage)
  ```

## Issues and improvements

- Issue 1: The image is too large for the widget. This should be solveable by passing `selector = "#htmlwidget_container"` instead of `cliprect = "viewport"` to `webshot`, but this didn't work in my tests. Alternatively, `plot_crop(myImage, quiet = TRUE)` can be added right after `webshot` to use `knitr`'s cropping mechanism.
- Issue 2: For some reason, the produced PDF is in black and white. When saving the screenshot as PNG, color will be preserved: `myImage <- "image.png"`. However, the fonts will be blurry and I didn't find a way to increase the resolution (the `webshot` argument `vwidth` doesn't help). Therefore, I would say it is a trade-off: You can either have non-blurry fonts (PDF), or colors (PNG).
- Issue 3: Messy temporary files. You can add `unlink(tmpHTML)` if you like.

## Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot)
library(formattable)

# Data from the question
df <- data.frame(
  Typ = c("Winners", "", "Losers", ""),
  Time = c("1.", "2.", "1.", "2."),
  Value = percent(c(0.22, 0.18, 0.78, 0.82)),
  Change = percent(c(NA, -0.04, NA, 0.04))
  )
mytable <- formattable(df, list(Change = formatter(
  "span",
  style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green")),
  x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)
  )))

tmpHTML <-  basename(tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
saveWidget(as.htmlwidget(mytable), file = tmpHTML)

myImage <- "image.pdf"
webshot(tmpHTML, file = myImage, cliprect = "viewport")

plot_crop(myImage, quiet = TRUE)
knitr::include_graphics(myImage)

unlink(tmpHTML)
@
\end{document}
```