# Render LaTeX tables in HTML using r-markdown

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to render the following table in a RMD file:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

So far no success. Is there any fundamental reason why rmarkdown cannot compile LaTeX enviroments (other than equations) to HTML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a markdown document, the expected input markup language is [(r)markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/). You should not expect `pandoc` to automatically recognize arbitrarily mixed markup languages. LaTeX math markup can only be used in markdown documents because there is a [rmarkdown extension](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#math) to handle this.

However, it is still possible to use a LaTeX table like the one shown in the question in a rmarkdown document. I demonstrated the "inverse" (markdown table in RNW document) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598367/2706569). Please note that this a rather experimental approach that might fail in other situations.

The idea behind the function `tex2markdown` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598367/2706569).

````
---
output: html_document
---

# My document

This is `rmarkdown`.

This table is converted from LaTeX:
```{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(knitr)

tex2markdown <- function(texstring) {
  writeLines(text = texstring,
             con = myfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".tex"))
  texfile <- pandoc(input = myfile, format = "html")
  cat(readLines(texfile), sep = "\n")
  unlink(c(myfile, texfile))
}

textable <- "
\\begin{table}[]
\\centering
\\caption{Food order}
\\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
\\hline
 Hamburgers & 3 \\\\ 
 Hot dogs & 2 \\\\ \\hline
\\end{tabular}
\\end{table}
"

tex2markdown(textable)
```

--- 

Time for *lunch*.
````

Not all LaTeX features can be converted to HTML, but for simple tasks this should work. Note that backslashes need to be escaped by an additional backslash.

This is mainly a proof of concept. For production, use LaTeX tables in RNW documents and markdown tables in RMD documents!