# How to import .tex file using RMarkdown and bookdown and word_document2

Tags: r, ms-word, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I would like to import a .tex file into my RMarkdown document. I am using bookdown and importantly need to export to Word via `word_document2`. Is it possible to do this? Here is the way I would do this using LaTeX:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Table Title}
\label{usnwr_id}
\centering
\scalebox{0.8}{
\input{\dir/filename.tex}}
\caption*{\footnotesize \emph{Notes: ...}}
\end{table}
```

If there is a way to retain the LaTeX code, that would be ideal (because I am transferring everything over).

And here is a skeleton version of filename.tex

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{llc}
\toprule
AA & BB & CC\\
\midrule
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but instead of scaling content which contains text, better choose an appropriate font size, this will give a better typographical result.

Comment: Good point. Thank you, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.

Comment: you can run tex code from anywhere inside the rmd by adding \input{filename.tex} (filename.tex can not inclue \usepackage (use header-includes) nor \begin{documen}) . This only works with pdf output to my knowledge.

Comment: Could you share the filename.tex file or at least a part of it? That would make it easier to test a few things.

Comment: Great suggestion, @JBGruber. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I tried solving this problem using `pandoc`. You can see an example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386808/render-latex-tables-in-html-using-r-markdown).

But as it was written [in another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326944/tables-missing-when-i-convert-latex-file-to-html-or-docx):

> This does not work for more complicated tables.

---

I asked some of my friends: "What would you do in this situation?"

One of them told me about [this tool](https://tableconvert.com/latex-to-markdown) to convert LaTeX tables to Markdown tables. It works nicely without tricky and big tables.

### Converting

Let's have a look at your table in LaTeX.

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{llc}
\toprule
AA & BB & CC\\
\midrule
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

The tool will convert the table into Markdown.

```
---
title: "test"
output:  
  word_document: default
---

| AA | BB | CC |
|:---:|:---:|:---:|
| a  | b  | c  |
```

And it looks like this in Microsoft Word.

### [image: Word Document]

---

This is all that I wanted to say. If it is not suitable for you or somebody couldn't solve this problem as expected – another option could be to try some R table packages like `gt`, `flextable`, `kableExtra`, or other packages of your choice.