# Render latex tables in xaringan presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown, xaringan

I am trying to include a Latex table in my xaringan presentation built in an rmarkdown. However, the table does not render. My code is the following, taken from the online example showing how to connect Latex with r (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html).

My document is set up with this:

````
---
title: "Presentation"
subtitle: ""
author: "author"
institute: "institute"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      keep_tex: yes
    css: xaringan-themer.css
    
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```


```{r xaringan-themer, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(xaringanthemer)
style_mono_accent(
  base_color = "blue",
  header_font_google = google_font("Lato"),
  text_font_google   = google_font("Lato", "300", "300i"),
  code_font_google   = google_font("Lato")
)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
```
````

The table I want to create is then included in the following chunk:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
A & B \\
A & B \\
\end{tabular}
```

Yet when I look in the infinite moon reader or knit, the latex code does not render. Instead, it looks like the following:

[image]

Why does this not render and how can I fix it, so that the table renders on the slide of my xaringan presentation? Am I misunderstanding how markdown works? Or do I need to do something more with bookdown in order to render the latex?

Comment: `xaringan` is an HTML output format, i.e. latex code will be printed as text in the output. IMHO easiest fix would be to create an HTML table or use one of the available packages which allow to create one, e.g. `kable`or `flextable`or ... But see [Render LaTeX tables in HTML using r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386808/render-latex-tables-in-html-using-r-markdown) which is essentially the same question and offers a possible approach to conver a latex table to an HTML table.